# How is PCI ROM shadowed?

Tags: hardware, boot, bios, pci, pci-bus

in several resources I found that: ROM image must be copied to RAM to 000C0000h through 000DFFFFh. If the Class Code indicates that this is the VGA device ROM, its code must be copied into memory starting at location 000C0000h.

1: What if I have PCI hungry hungry hippo card that has ROM bigger than 128KB?

2: What if I have regular PCI device that has ROM 64KB but I have 4 of them? Are they loaded sequentially into this memory range? If so (though I doubt that) how is the code image preserved between init and boot phase?

3: What would happen if BIOS decided to go nonconformist and designated a different memory location? Why is it important to use this range anyway?

4: how the hell is regular case different from VGA interface? Is it just the limit that makes the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: It is not possible to have ROM this big copied into option ROM space. Init size field is 1 byte and it is interpreted as 512 byte increments, that's 255 * 512 = 127KB

2: Too bad, some of them won't be initialized.

3: There are PAMs in the northbridge(intel chipset datasheet). These registers can write protected specific ranges in optional ROM space.

4: Limit counts for VGA too. It just has to start at c0000h, while some NIC can start at.. pfft d0000h as well.

Thank you Pyjong.
You are welcome Pyjong.

Answer (score 6):

1. non-UEFI BIOS Option ROMs aren't typically that large and had size restrictions, but UEFI drivers can be larger and placed above 1MiB in a UEFI bios, which switches out of real mode during the SEC phase. You can [disable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41059_01/html/E48312/napsm.z40000081405760.html) certain option ROMs that you don't want to be shadowed to the space next boot.
2. This small range was used because non-UEFI BIOSes operate in real mode (interrupt table (IVT as opposed to IDT) starts at 0h as a guarantee to option ROMs) and therefore can only access the first 1MiB of memory and need memory for other things (BIOS data, BIOS, stack/heap for BIOS and option ROMs). Although, most BIOSes ended up using unreal mode or protected mode with virtual 8086 so they could use the IVT and address 32 bits at the same time, so nothing is stopping the BIOS from shadowing option ROMs elsewhere in RAM and the BIOS scanning that region (I have read that E0000–EFFFF can also be used if the BIOS is only 64KiB), except this gets complicated if the option ROMs themselves look for other option ROMs like the UNDI ROM looking for the BC ROM on a PxE NIC. They also used [PMM](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/pci-expansion-rom/#gref) services to allocate 16/32 bit heap addresses. UEFI no longer uses BIOS interrupt services; it uses EFI functions.
3. The option ROM for onboard graphics is in the BIOS itself and its address is known. It is classically hardcoded to be moved to C0000h (C000:0000h in real mode segmentation notation), or indeed wherever it wants. The BIOS makes sure at least that it is the first option ROM that is executed, but if it knows it moved it to D0000h for instance then it knows where to pass control. If it were allowed to be at a variable address rather than a fixed address then it could end up not being able to fit in the range if other PCIe cards are shadowed first. Also, it would have to scan for the VGA bios class code first and then scan the range again or keep an internal table of where option ROMs are, which is more convoluted than a simple routine that linearly iterates across the space and the video BIOS always happens to be executed first. So it needs a fixed address, and if it makes the fixed address D0000h rather than C0000h and places other option ROMs around it, then external fragmentation of the space will occur.

The PAMs aren't in the northbridge anymore (which doesn't exist on modern Intel CPUs), they're used as part of the SADs' configuration in the L3 cache slice, which decode the address and either send a request to the memory controller, DMI, PCIe link or processor graphics. The BIOS can set the PAM so that reads for a certain range are sent to DMI and writes are sent to the memory controller. That way the BIOS can shadow onto itself and PCI(e) XROMBARs can be set to the same exact address to which they're going to be shadowed.

On my system (Kaby lake + C230 series PCH + UEFI Secure Boot disabled), there are 3 option ROMs in the C0000h–DFFFFh region.

**VGA BIOS**

```
Option ROM Header: 0x000C0000
55 AA 80 E9 91 F9 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 U.....0000000000
30 30 A8 2F E9 B1 2E AF 40 00 90 0B             00./....@...    
  Signature 0xAA55
  Length    0x80 (65536 bytes)
  Initialization entry  0x30F991E9 //software read this wrong it's actually 0xF991E9, which is a 16 bit relative jump 0xF991; -1647
  Reserved  0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 
  Reserved  0x30 0xA8 0x2F 0xE9 0xB1 0x2E 0xAF 
  PCI Data Offset   0x0040 //offset is from start of OpROM header
  Expansion Header Offset   0x0B90

PCI Data Structure: 0x000C0040
50 43 49 52 86 80 06 04 1C 00 1C 00 03 00 00 03 PCIR............
80 00 00 00 00 80 80 00                         ........        
  Signature PCIR
  Vendor ID 0x8086 - Intel Corporation
  Device ID 0x0406
  Product Data  0x001C
  Structure Length  0x001C
  Structure Revision    0x03
  Class Code    0x00 0x00 0x03
  Image Length  0x0080
  Revision Level    0x0000
  Code Type 0x00
  Indicator 0x80
  Reserved  0x0080
```

**SATA Controller** (PnP Expansion Header for each disk)

```
Option ROM Header: 0x000D0000
55 AA 4D B8 00 01 CB 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 U.M.............
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 A0 00 9A 01             ............    
  Signature 0xAA55
  Length    0x4D (39424 bytes)
  Initialization entry  0xCB0100B8 //mov  ax, 0x100  retf 
  Reserved  0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
  Reserved  0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x15 
  PCI Data Offset   0x00A0
  Expansion Header Offset   0x019A

PCI Data Structure: 0x000D00A0
50 43 49 52 86 80 2A 28 1C 00 1C 00 03 00 04 01 PCIR..*(........
4D 00 02 0F 00 80 4D 00                         M.....M.        
  Signature PCIR
  Vendor ID 0x8086 - Intel Corporation
  Device ID 0x282A
  Product Data  0x001C
  Structure Length  0x001C
  Structure Revision    0x03
  Class Code    0x00 0x04 0x01
  Image Length  0x004D
  Revision Level    0x0F02
  Code Type 0x00
  Indicator 0x80
  Reserved  0x004D

PnP Expansion Header: 0x000D019A
24 50 6E 50 01 02 BA 01 01 06 00 00 00 00 C2 00 $PnP............
D4 00 00 04 01 C4 90 1A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
  Signature $PnP
  Revision  0x01
  Length    0x02 (32 bytes)
  Next Header   0x01BA
  Reserved  0x01
  Checksum  0x06
  Device ID 0x00000000
  Manufacturer  0x00C2 - Intel Corporation  //location 0xD00C2
  Product Name  0x00D4 - SanDisk X400 M.2 2280 256GB //location 0xD00D4
  Device Type Code  0x00 0x04 0x01
  Device Indicators 0xC4
  Boot Connection Vector    0x1A90
  Disconnect Vector 0x0000
  Bootstrap Entry Vector    0x0000
  Reserved  0x0000
  Resource info. vector 0x0000

PnP Expansion Header: 0x000D01BA
24 50 6E 50 01 02 00 00 02 9B 00 00 00 00 C2 00 $PnP............
F5 00 00 04 01 C4 94 1A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
  Signature $PnP
  Revision  0x01
  Length    0x02 (32 bytes)
  Next Header   0x0000 //next PnP expansion header contains nothing useful
  Reserved  0x02
  Checksum  0x9B
  Device ID 0x00000000
  Manufacturer  0x00C2 - Intel Corporation
  Product Name  0x00F5 - ST1000LM035-1RK172
  Device Type Code  0x00 0x04 0x01
  Device Indicators 0xC4
  Boot Connection Vector    0x1A94
  Disconnect Vector 0x0000
  Bootstrap Entry Vector    0x0000
  Reserved  0x0000
  Resource info. vector 0x0000
```

**Ethernet Controller**

```
Option ROM Header: 0x000DA000
55 AA 08 E8 76 10 CB 55 BC 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 U...v..U........
00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 40 00 60 00             ...... .@.`.    
  Signature 0xAA55
  Length    0x08 (4096 bytes)
  Initialization entry  0xCB1076E8 //call then far return 
  Reserved  0x55 0xBC 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
  Reserved  0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 
  PXEROMID Offset  0x0020 //RWEverything didn't pick it up as a separate field and made it part of the reserved section so I separated it.
  PCI Data Offset   0x0040  
  Expansion Header Offset   0x0060

UNDI ROM ID Structure: 0x000DA020  //not recognised by RW Everything so I parsed it myself
55 4E 44 49 16 08 00 00 01 02 32 0D 00 08 B0 C4  UNDI......2...
80 46 50 43 49 52                                ¦-ÇFPCIR
  Signature  UNDI
  StructLength  0x16
  Checksum  0x08  
  StructRev  0x00
  UNDIRev 0x00 0x01 0x02
  UNDI Loader Offset 0x0D32
  StackSize 0x0800
  DataSize 0xC4B0
  CodeSize 0x4680
  BusType PCIR

PCI Data Structure: 0x000DA040
50 43 49 52 EC 10 68 81 00 00 1C 00 03 00 00 02 PCIR..h.........
08 00 01 02 00 80 08 00                         ........        
  Signature PCIR
  Vendor ID 0x10EC - Realtek Semiconductor
  Device ID 0x8168
  Product Data  0x0000
  Structure Length  0x001C
  Structure Revision    0x03
  Class Code    0x00 0x00 0x02
  Image Length  0x0008
  Revision Level    0x0201
  Code Type 0x00
  Indicator 0x80
  Reserved  0x0008

PnP Expansion Header: 0x000DA060
24 50 6E 50 01 02 00 00 00 D7 00 00 00 00 AF 00 $PnP............
92 01 02 00 00 E4 00 00 00 00 C1 0B 00 00 00 00 ................
  Signature $PnP
  Revision  0x01
  Length    0x02 (32 bytes)
  Next Header   0x0000
  Reserved  0x00
  Checksum  0xD7
  Device ID 0x00000000
  Manufacturer  0x00AF - Intel Corporation
  Product Name  0x0192 - Realtek PXE B02 D00
  Device Type Code  0x02 0x00 0x00
  Device Indicators 0xE4
  Boot Connection Vector    0x0000
  Disconnect Vector 0x0000
  Bootstrap Entry Vector    0x0BC1 // will be at 0xDABC1
  Reserved  0x0000
  Resource info. vector 0x0000
```

On another computer with a legacy BIOS, only the VGA option ROM appears in a scan of this region, and at 0xC0000. No EHCI and no SATA. This suggests to me it's embedded in the BIOS but part of the BIOS code and not as an option ROM, which is known as a BAID in the BBS; the code to initialise the controller and scan for boot devices and enter their info in the IPL table and hook int 13h so the MBR/VBR can access the disk is hardcoded in the BIOS. Also, BCV hook order priorities no longer matter because they're all entered into the IPL table as BAIDs anyway nowadays rather than just disk 80h being bootable (populated by reading from the current disk enumeration no. in the BDA and then filling in that many entries with their respective details acquired from int 13h calls). Presumably, the IPL table contains the disk number to boot from and passes it to the vector in the entry which will be the code shared by all BAIDs which loads the first sector from the disk using int 13h to 0x7c00 checks for a valid MBR and then passes control. The MBR will then move itself away from 0x7c00 and load the active partition's first sector i.e. the VBR to 0x7c00 and pass control to it, which will be the JMP instruction (if its the default windows one. If its GRUB, it will load and pass control to core.img from sectors 1–65). The VBR will then load the IPL in sectors 1–15 which it locates on the disk using the HiddenSectors value in the BPB in the VBR and passes control to it. For further details on Windows boot from this point, see my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1306864/how-does-the-windows-boot-manager-locate-the-bcd/1642902#1642902).

The code in the initialisation entry on the SATA controller is a code that far returns 0x100. This appears to have been modified by the BIOS or option ROM itself after the initialisation has taken place, or maybe just a dud because it's an embedded device that is initialised elsewhere in the BIOS. By definition, the initialisation code is now useless and option ROMs that adhere to DDIM may remove the initialisation code from RAM once it has been initialised and recompute the length and checksum. The video bios even does some negative relative jump. This suggests that the BIOS shadows its video BIOS to a location before C0000h, shadowing partially over the VGA VRAM region, such that the option ROM header appears at C0000h.

'length' appears to be describing the amount of space in the legacy option ROM shadow RAM region it takes up after initialisation of the option ROM.

Here is an example memory map of a split PXE option ROM:

[image]

Rather than setting all the XROMBARs in one go such that it includes the pre-initialised length, the BIOS probably loads and initialises one at a time. It can't overwrite / remove the option ROM because routines in the option ROM separate to the IPL code may still be called by the BCV to interact with the hardware. For instance, after the video BIOS initialisation code has run, the PCI configuration space is scanned and the first XROMBAR that returns a length will be set to the end of the video BIOS. Reads are then directed to DMI and writes directed to memory. It then shadows it to memory, redirects reads to RAM, and performs a far call to the initialisation entry. The IPL code then shrinks itself by removing the initialisation code. The BIOS checks the new size of the option ROM and for PnP expansion headers and registers BEVs/BCVs. It then redirects loads back to DMI and loads the next XROMBAR. The BIOS builds the BCV table entry at a time and then executes the BCVs in order of BCV priority.

An option ROM could move the BEV/BCV to a PMM allocation in extended memory, leaving a jump instruction at the BEV/BCV offset but that would break relative addressing of jumps in the BCV/BEV into functions in the rest of the option ROM. It could therefore relocate its whole self to a PMM allocation and reduce the size to just the headers, but clearly this isn't the case with most option ROMs. A BEV does relocate the UNDI driver though.